# Why doesn't my console show a result based on code below

Tags: javascript, function

Why doesn't my console show the results of the function markTipCalculator? The last line of code I would have thought would have called that function and returned a result in my console.

```
function markTipCalculator(){
markBills = [77, 375, 110, 45];
let markSmallBillPercent = .20;
let markMediumBillPercent = .10;
let markLargeBillPercent = .25;
let markSmallTip = 0
let markMediumTip = 0
let markLargeTip = 0
    for (i of markBills){
        let markBillAmts = i
        switch (true){
            case markBillAmts < 100:
                markSmallBillAmount = markBillAmts * markSmallBillPercent;
                markSmallTip += markSmallBillAmount;
               break;
            case markBillAmts >= 100 && markBillAmts<= 300:
                markMediumBillAmount = markBillAmts * markMediumBillPercent;
                markMediumTip += markMediumBillAmount;
               break;
            case markBillAmts > 300:
                markLargeBillAmount = markBillAmts * markLargeBillPercent;
                markLargeTip += markLargeBillAmount;
               break;
            default: 
            console.log('We have an error somewhere');
        } 
        };
       return (markSmallTip + markMediumTip + markLargeTip)
};
markTipCalculator();
```

Comment: I see the result `129.15`. What do you expect?

Comment: Yeah that is the correct result but the last line of code has to have console.log(markTipCalculator) for it to show in my console but I thought the last line of code as is would return 129.15 in my console. But just with the code above and refreshing my console I would have nothing showing in my console.

Comment: _”but I thought the last line of code as is would return 129.15 in my console“_ — why would it? You’re not doing anything with the result. The fact that the console shows the result of a completion record (usually the last line) only applies to a REPL-like environment (i.e. copy-pasting code into the console and hitting `Enter`). If you run this code in a normal script (or module) and want the value `markTipCalculator()` to be _logged_, then you need to use the `console.log` method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't see anything in your console because you aren't logging anything to your console. Try `console.log(markTipCalculator())`

Comment: But shouldn't the return statement in the 3rd to last line of code return something to the console? If my last line of code is calling the function and the function has a return statement in it wouldn't that return a result to the console? You can tell I am a beginner obviously. Trying to understand this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The console doesn't show all returned values automatically. If you want something to show up there you have to use one of the logging methods of the console object. I.E. console.log(), console.error() or console.info(). MDN is your friend! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console